# What provider for Android native SIP

Tags: android, sip

I'm trying to create a small SIP application using Android native SIP (using the code from here (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html).  However it does not seem to register properly with the SIP provider, I'm trying linphone.org and getonsip.com.  Has anybody actually made it work with some SIP provider?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Linphone works great for me, managed to get it working even with a 8 devices confrence!, the call quality is good and there is barely noticeable delay in good networks, its way better then the native sip.

You should work with Linphone.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Linphone.  However this does not answer my question.  The question is which SIP provider works with native Android SIP.

Comment: @mehturt well I did some calls using the native application that uses sip in the android OS itself, it is bad, both in the quality of the sound and in the delay it produces. i wouldnt recommand using it at all... so if you asking me finding it a SIP provider is a waste of time at least until they get it better...

Comment: It's fine for my application, I only need to establish call and send DTMF.  But I can't even go through the registration, hence this question.