# How do i create SIP accounts on the fly?

Tags: android, sip, voip, linphone

I want to implement voice calling in my app. [According to Androids SIP documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) all I need is an SIP account, but [according to this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577811/what-provider-for-android-native-sip), [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/) is my best bet. Using Linphone, i noticed how they have a whole separate app just for creating SIP accounts. My question is, is it possible to create such an account programmatically in my app void of user intervention. Ideally i would like to set it up when the user creates an account for my app.

P.S: Im new to this SIP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you you want to generate SIP accounts with a "public" VOIP provider. While, it is possible to create the accounts on the fly, you with have to create it on their terms and inputs (such as username, password, email addresses, SIP domain etc). Therefore for a 100 accounts you might need these parameters.

However, I don't advise you do this as, especially if you want to create a white-list.

From my experience, it is much better to create multiple addresses separately and then allocate them to your devices. It is much easier to manage and also scalable.

Comment: can you please provide some references on how i can go about it using your approach,

Comment: Are you using Linphone addresses or paid for addresses?

Comment: Linphone addresses

Answer (score 0):

Each VoIP server has a a different API for this. Usually a simple HTTP GET/POST API.

So it is not possible to make an universal solution, but you must check your server or VoIP provider specification for this and implement accordingly.